# Combine 2 arrays of different lengths and sort date

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have 2 arrays with different lengths

`let daysArray = ['09-20', '09-21', '09-22', '09-23', '09-24', '09-25', '09-26']`

`let weekNameArray = ['Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa + So', 'Mo', 'Di' ]`

combined them with _.zipWith:

```
let weakDateArr = _.zipWith(weekNameArray, daysArray , function(first, second) {
          return first + " " + second  
        });
```

*How I can combine them to get the next array:*

`['Mi 09-20', 'Do 09-21', 'Fr 09-22', 'Sa + So', 'Mo 09-25', 'Di 09-26']`

'Sa + So' must be undated *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, not sure lodash has support for this out of box...

You could apply a simple custom solution using `Array.map()` and an index offset for the `daysArray`:

```
days_offset = 0;
let combined = weekNameArray.map( (name, index) => {
    if(name.length <= 2) {
    return name + ' ' + daysArray[ index - days_offset ];
  } else {
    days_offset += 1;
    return name;
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you very much!
exactly what is needed